# What is going wrong with this Tic-Tac-Toe game code?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game for Python, and the board isn't changing when it should.

I've verified that the code inside the if statement is being run, so I know that isn't the problem.

```py
#defines the Tic-Tac-Toe board (dictionary)
board={'L1':' ','M1':' ','R1':' ',
       'L2':' ','M2':' ','R2':' ',
       'L3':' ','M3':' ','R3':' '}
#if the computer or the player are about to get three in a row (this is only one of the many combinations I added)
if board['L1']==board['L2']!=' ' and board['L3']==' ':
    #x1 is a variable that determines if the player is X's or O's (first or second)
    if x1==1:
        board['L3']=='O'
        else:
            board['L3']=='X'
        #board
        played=1
```

Here's the link to my full code: https://repl.it/repls/BruisedBusyGraph (Try running it with difficulty level 2)

I expected the board to change its L3 attribute to either X or O after the code was run, but it stayed blank even after running the if statement.

Comment: "board['L1']==board['L2']!=' '" what is it really supposed to do?

Comment: Did you mean to have an `and` or `or` in there?

Comment: The "board['L1']==board['L2']!=' '" was supposed to test if the L1 and L2 spaces on the board were both filled with either an X or an O (if they're equal and not empty). I did mean to have an and in there, since the spaces had to be equal and the third space had to be empty for the computer to play.

Comment: Unless I'm too tired that's not how it works. And if I'm tired, it is anyway proof that you're writing cryptic code. board['L1'] != ' ' and board['L2'] != ' ' and xxx . If you see a pattern there don't try to obfuscate it with shortcuts but rethink how you implemented it.

Comment: OK, my bad on this one, that's actually correct :)

Comment: @DawsonKern You should really look at using functions/classes, your code is far more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems comes from this part:

```
if x1==1:
    board['L3']=='O'
    else:
        board['L3']=='X'
```

You are mixing the equality test `==` and the assignment operator `=`

Changing this part with the following should work:

```
if x1==1:
    board['L3']='O'
    else:
        board['L3']='X'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.